# Xamarin Forms: OnMeasure() in CarouselView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm using Rainman's CarouselView.  The item views do not receive OnMeasure() or OnSizeRequest().  Is there a flag to turn this on?  Is there another function I can override to control the size of the item view?

My problem is that in iOS the views are too tall: they extend beyond the boundary of the screen.  It does not happen right away, but always happens when the phone's orientation is changed.  In Android everything is peachy.

Comment: It's better to provide illustration to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah well.  While I still don't know why item views of the CarouselView do not receive OnMeasure(), I fixed my problem by catching the **CarouselView**'s OnMeasure() and setting the minimum requested size to (1,1).